# Calling python module from Java

Tags: java, python

I want to call a function from a python module from Java using "PythonInterpreter" and here's my Java code

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

interpreter.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages')\nimport helloworld");

PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("helloworld.getName");

PyObject result = someFunc.__call__();

String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);

System.out.println(realResult);
```

and the Python code (helloworld.py) is below:

```
    from faker import Factory
    fake = Factory.create()

    def getName():
       name = fake.name()
       return name
```

The problem I'm facing is while I'm calling interpreter.get when it returns a null PyObject.

Any idea what's going wrong? The python code runs fine from IDLE

## EDIT

I just did a bit of change in the code as below

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

interpreter.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages')\nimport helloworld");


PyInstance wrapper = (PyInstance)interpreter.eval("helloworld" + "(" + ")");  

PyObject result = wrapper.invoke("getName()");

String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);

System.out.println(realResult);
```

and I introduced a class in my python module

```
from faker import Factory

class helloworld:

def init(self):
    fake = Factory.create()

def getName():
    name = fake.name()
    return name
```

Now am getting the error below

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: call of non-function (java package 'helloworld')
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jython, but what happens if you try to `.get("helloworld")` instead? Or what if you `.getLocals()`?

Comment: nope...no luck, throwing TypeError: call of non-function (instance of 'org.python.core.PyStringMap') with getLocals

Comment: Wouldn't the class constructor be `helloworld.helloworld()` if you're doing `import helloworld` instead of `from helloworld import helloworld`?

Comment: Also, `def init(self): fake = ...` should be `def __init__(self): self.fake = ...` and `getName` should take `self` if you're storing the fake on an instance variable.

Answer (score 5):

1. You cannot use python attribute access in [`PythonInterpreter.get`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#get(java.lang.String)). Just use attribute name to get the module, and retrieve attribute from it.
2. (EDIT PART) Python code is totally broken. Please see the proper example below. And, of course, [www.python.org](http://www.python.org).
3. (EDIT PART) First parameter of [`PyInstance.invoke`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/PyInstance.html#invoke(java.lang.String)) should be method name.
4. Below you can find working code sample for both cases

Main.java

```
import org.python.core.*;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test1();
        test2();
    }

    private static void test1() {
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.exec("import hello_world1");
        PyObject func = interpreter.get("hello_world1").__getattr__("get_name");
        System.out.println(func.__call__().__tojava__(String.class));
    }

    private static void test2() {
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.exec("from hello_world2 import HelloWorld");
        PyInstance obj = (PyInstance)interpreter.eval("HelloWorld()");
        System.out.println(obj.invoke("get_name").__tojava__(String.class));
    }
}
```

hello_world1.py

```
def get_name():
    return "world"
```

hello_world2.py

```
class HelloWorld:
    def __init__(self):
        self.world = "world"

    def get_name(self):
        return self.world
```

Comment: in your solution how could you pass arguments to `get_name(self, something)`?