# How to make .jar file of a python script and use it in java project

Tags: java, jython

I have an object detection code in python, I want to use the o/p of this code in my android studio project to create an app. For this I want to create a .jar file of this python script.
But I can't seem to find the right steps to make the .jar file and add it to android studio.
I'm using jython on windows to create the .jar file.
If there are other ways I can integrate this python code with java, please list them.

Comment: https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/visadtutor/compile.html

Comment: Have you already give a look into this library: https://github.com/joaoventura/pybridge

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling python module from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697315/calling-python-module-from-java)

Comment: I can't import python interpreter in android studio.

Comment: How can I use a specific python script in my native android app using pybridge.