# Can you make an android app with imported python modules?

Tags: python, android, module

Can you make an android app with your own imported python modules, lets say I wanted to use for example the yfinance module?

What application would you use and how would you go about it?

Comment: It seems that a similar question is asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697315/calling-python-module-from-java

Comment: That is to do with java importing python modules, not using python modules for android apps, thanks though.